# Add existing Azure Container Instance to VNET

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-container-service, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I have an existing ACI. Can I add it to a VNET and Subnet via Azure CLI/Azure cloud shell.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible right now from the CLI, the `az container` commands don't support patching / upgrading an existing container instance or container group for the network profile property

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-update#properties-that-require-container-delete

If you are interested in not loosing the traffic going to your existing ACI, you should deploy a new ACI to a private VNET/Subnet and front both your containers using an applicationGW or Load Balancer on your new VNET/Subnet.

Once ready to make the move you should be direct all traffic to your ACI running in the VNET.